# Pyramid data exchange between templates and views

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyramid

I am trying to pass some data from the template to my views.py, do some processing with it, and then pass back the data to the template. I initially had no idea how to do this but after browsing through google and Stackoverflow, I tried a solution which seemed a bit unambiguous to me. This is what I tried.

My views.py:-

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemp.pt')
def my_view(request):

    data = request.POST["data"]
    process(data) #function that does something with my data
    return {'project': 'myproject','content':data}
mytemp.pt
```

a small javascript snippet followed by the html where my data goes

```
$.post(
    "{{request.route_url('home')}}", 
    {'data': 'HelloWoRld'} 
);
<body>"${content}"</body>
```

This gives me the error

```
raise KeyError("No key %r: %s" % (key, self.reason))
KeyError: "No key 'data': Not a form request"
```

I dont want any forms and submit buttons here. The data thats getting passed can be anything. From a file to a variable to just a preference. And the passing can occur with a button click possibly.
I hope there's a better/correct way to pass information back and forth between views and templates? Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: When do you get the error?  When initially loading the page or on execution of the javascript snippet?

If you're initially going to your page, you might need a check first
`if request.method == 'POST':`

because on just browsing to the page it would be a `GET` and there wouldn't be a `request.POST['data']` available...

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly enter your route, instead of `{{request.route_url('home')}}`?

Comment: @peter: I am not invoking my snippet yet . where do I invoke it? I just have this snippet but I am not sure how to trigger it or if it automatically triggers. It would be very helpful if you direct me stepwise how to pass data back and forth. I tried but couldn't get it.

Comment: @Raj: could you please add an answer with steps and possibly an explanation to the above problem? I have used a form submit data transfer before but now my data has nothing to do with form submissions.is it possible to normally send data to view once the user enters something in a box or some variable that gets passed on button click? Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Can you show your `__init__.py` (I'm specifically looking for the routes you've set up)?

Comment: Hi I have figured out a way to pass info from templates to views. I shall post it as an answer below. Kindly let me know if there are other ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

Hi after bit of research and toil, I have figured out a way to accomplish this.
IN my templates, I have this ajax method that posts data to view as follows

```
$.ajax({     
    type: "POST",
    url: "/home",
    data: {contents:myvar},
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        alert("Success!");
} });
```

And then get the posted variable inside my views.py as follows:

```
viewcontents=request.POST.get('contents')
```

And that's one fine working way to pass data from templates to views. ANy other ways to accomplish this are welcome. :)

Comment: If you rephrase "pass data from templates to views" as "pass data from an HTML page displayed in user's browser to Python code which runs on my server" I think things will become much clearer. Do not think of the generated page displayed in the browser as of "template" - the fact that it was generated from a template is completely coincidental.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I just wanted to retain the Pyramid terminology which is why I termed it that way. :)